# How to start an app's target in the IOS-Simulator from a shell command

Tags: xcode, shell, ios-simulator

- I have XCode 7.2
- I have an App coded in XCode named MYAPP.
- I have created a target from my MYAPP named MYAPP_NEWTARGET
- I know howto start the IOS Simulator from the shell:

  ```
  open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app
  ```

Question:
How can I start my target MYAPP_NEWTARGET from the shell command ? something fictitius like :

```
   open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app --startapp=MYAPP --apptarget=MYAPP_NEWTARGET
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simctl to do this once the device is booted in Simulator.app:

```
xcrun simctl install booted /path/to/your.app
xcrun simctl launch booted your.app.identifier
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know where I can find my App /path/to/your.app in the filesystem ?

Comment: I don't know where it would be on your filesystem.  You're creating it, so you should know where it is.  If you're using Xcode, look in your `build` directory.